# Sentinel Value in Java

Tags: java, loops, infinite, sentinel

I'm just starting out with java, and for my intro class must create loops with a sentinel value of 0 to convert entered USD to GBP. There is some run-time error and it appears I've created in infinite loop. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Prompts user for today's conversion of USD to GBP
 * Then prompts user for USD value, which will inform user of GBP
 * Prompting loop for other USD values, util sentinel value of (0) is encountered
 * hint: while loop shouldnt include prompt for exchange rate. When user enteres 0, program will print terminating "goodbye" message and end
 */
public class AP6_DollarToPound
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       double amount = 0;
       int rate = in.nextInt();
       int value = in.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter today's US Dollar to British Pound Sterling exchange rate: ");
       System.out.println("Enter a value in US Dollars: ");

       while (value != 0);
       {
           value = in.nextInt();
           if (value != 0)
           {
               amount = rate * value;
               System.out.println("Value in GBP is: " + value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding to the other answers you also print `value` when you should print `amount` instead.

Comment: Thank you all very much! The stack overflow community is so helpful when learning programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You while loop is wrong.

```
while (value != 0);
```

This means iterate while value is not zero. And in this case it is always not zero.

You should do something like this:

```
while (value != 0) 
{ 
    // Change value as you like
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you accidentally typed a ';' after the while loop causing the inner elements to never be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your order is a little mixed up.

If you want to show a description for whatever the user should enter, then that call to `System.out.println()` must come before your call to `Scanner.nextInt()`.

In your case it would show a blank screen, wait until the user enters two numbers separated by whitespaces or linebreaks, then display your two lines. Then it only continues if the second number entered by the user was not zero, in which case it waits for him to enter another number. If that number is zero, the loop continues with more input requests until there is finally one that is not zero. Only then will it output your result.

You might also want to check if the input is actually a number and not just any string of characters. That can be done by checking `Scanner.hasNextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize amount to 1 not 0
Double amount = 1;
Because in multiplecation 1 is didnt have effect on the operation

Comment: he overrides the initialization anyway